No lights, ambient occlusion, or emmision but object still lighted
I'm doing testing with geometry nodes and textures and when i go into rendered, cycles, the objects are illuminated even though the light object is disabled and there isnt an ambient occlusion option im seeing. Ive turned the strength of the background to 0, and tested to see if it was my shaders but nothing worked.


Please share your file

In your settings you have disabled Scene World. So instead of whatever you have set as background, Blender uses the default HDRI which is used for Material Preview to light the scene. I don't think we need your file.

when i enable the scene world only the grass specifically turns completely black, even if i have a light turned on

you can see the colors, because you plug the colors directly into the output (mixed shader), instead of first route them through "real" shaders.
If you add real shaders, as you can see in the image, you will get your wished black screen:

if you then e.g. add an HDRI as world shader, you will get:

